# MQTT receiving sensor data from different topics but coming across in one payload

Tags: arduino, mqtt, payload

Presently I have 2 sensor readings arriving as one payload from 2 topics( or it looks that way), what would be the recommended way to  split this one payload into 2 variables(temp, humidity);

The sensor readings are from different topics.

I have tried all manner of ways a person with little experience would try from for loops to try and write half the data to the serial monitor but to no avail.

I tried to enter the topic into this function but it would not compile.

```
void messageReceived(MQTTClient*client, char topic[], char payload[], int payload_length) {
  for (byte i=0;i<6;i++){ 
    Serial.print(payload[i]);
 }
}
```

the output on the serial monitor would be

```
23.4555.33
```

if I put a println after the for loop I get

```
23.45
55.33
```

Should I have 2  void messageReceived? one for temp and the other for humidity?

say

```
messageReceivedtemp()

messageReceivedHum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not receiving a single message, you are receiving separate 2 messages.

You have 2 problems with your code.

1. First you are not checking the topic that the message is arriving on, so you do not know which value is which.
2. You are just passing the values directly to the serial port without checking the length. You are using a fixed value of 6, but you should be using the `payload_length` value.

The code should read something like this:

```
void messageReceived(MQTTClient*client, char topic[], char payload[], int payload_length) {

  if (strcmp(topic, "temp") == 0) {
    //message arrived on the 'temp' topic
    Serial.print("temp: ");
  } else if (strcmp(topic, "hum") == 0 {
    //message arrived on the 'hum' topic
    Serial.print("hum: ");
  }

  for (int i=0;i<payload_length;i++){ 
    Serial.print(payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi,

That worked really well, I will remember that function to compare strings.  Thank-you.

I had the number 6 in as was trying to define the number of characters so that the first 4 would be a temp and 2nd 4 would be humidity. Either way, it did not work as you confirmed there were 2 messages being received.

All I done then was to use the function atof() to convert humidity/temp from char to float so that I can use them as variables later on.

Thanks again :)